# How to design layouts in android?

Tags: android

i am new to android ,i dont have idea of layouts,where to refer?
basic of layout desigining,and how to make the form scrollable ,such things etc

Regards
Rakesh shankar.P

Answer (score 6):

I'd say there most of what you need to know is available at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com). Specifically:

- [User Interface/Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html#Layout)
- [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html#Layout)

In general, I'd say there are two layouts that are used rather frequently:

- **LinearLayout** which can contain *rows* or *columns* of child nodes, depending on its `orientation`. The space available is distributed to the child nodes depending on their `weight`.
- **RelativeLayout** which allows for positioning of certain nodes specifically in relation to other nodes, with attributes such as `below` and `toRightOf`.

To make an area scrollable, you simply place it within a `ScrollView`